# git-crypt unlock is not working as expected I can't see the plain text

Tags: git-crypt

in my project we are using git-crypt to crypt and decrypt some files, but I have already created and added my pub key to the project using `gpg --full-generate-key` and `gpg --export myemail > my_key.pub` commands. I don't have any error message in the console, but I am not able to see the decrypted file, is there any way to check the logs?

Any ideas?